# "holding their own internal lives at bay"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following is a passage from [this](http://www.salon.com/2011/10/26/why_i_refuse_to_text_message/) article:

> The shift from emails to texts simply accelerates the process by which people are holding their own **internal lives** at bay. After all, if some future editor had the misfortune of combing through an archive of your text messages, I doubt she would find much that revealed who you truly were.

What does *interal life* mean mentioned in the passage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Internal**.

- Of or relating to mental or spiritual nature:

I think it refers to the level of privacy which technology appears to 'violate' since all we do can be controlled and  checked now and in the future.

Comment: Did you actually read the article?

Comment: The meaning of 'internal, I gave corresponds to what you say in your answer ' personality and emotional life'

Answer (score 0):

The context provided by the article makes it clear that by *"people holding their own internal lives at bay"*, the writer means "the obfuscation or concealment of one's actual personality and emotional life behind an uninformative barrier of brief and superficial text messages" (I paraphrase).